# registration.showNotification is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker

I'm using [serviceworker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin) to create a service worker in my reactjs apps.

I've followed [the example](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin/tree/master/docs) to register the service worker in the main thread. I've learnt that `Html5 Notification` doesn't work on Android chrome, so I used `registration.showNotification('Title', { body: 'Body.'});` instead of `new Notification('...')` to push notifications. But when I tested it on the desktop chrome, it throws this error

```
registration.showNotification is not a function
```

Is the registration.showNotification only available on Android chrome but not on the desktop?

```
public componentDidMount(){

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator &&
        (window.location.protocol === 'https:' || window.location.hostname === 'localhost')
    ) {
        const registration = runtime.register();

        registerEvents(registration, {
            onInstalled: () => {

                registration.showNotification('Title', { body: 'Body.'});
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log('serviceWorker not available')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runtime.register()` returns a JavaScript Promise, which is why you are getting a `not a function` error because Promises don't have a `showNotification()` method.

Instead, you'd have to chain a `.then()` callback to it in order to get the actual `registration` object (or use async/await, which is also cool).

```
runtime.register().then(registration => {
    registration.showNotification(...);
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Hope there's a typescript definition for service worker.

Answer (score 2):

***Below solution worked for me. Can try.***

The main root cause of ***.showNotification()*** not firing is service worker. Service worker is not getting registered. So it wont call ***registration.showNotification()*** method.

- Add ***service-worker.js*** file to your **project root directory**
- You can download ***service-worker.js*** file from [Link](https://gist.github.com/vanbrabantf/76586a7d069d0e42922123c4046c1286)

Use below code to register service worker and fire *registration.showNotification()* method.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log("Message received. ", payload);
            NotisElem.innerHTML = NotisElem.innerHTML + JSON.stringify(payload);
            //foreground notifications

            if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

                navigator.serviceWorker
                    .register('./service-worker.js', { scope: './' })
                    .then(function (registration) {
                        console.log("Service Worker Registered");
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, {
                                body: payload.data.body,
                                data: payload.data.link
                            });
                            registration.update();
                        }, 100);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
                    })

     }
 });
```